Msys 'bash -c' behaves differently from Git Bash than from cmd.exe
Trying to diagnose why an MSYS command fails within a buildsystem when it is invoked from Git Bash, even though the buildsystem succeeds when it is invoked from CMD.
I've noticed that, when I invoke this command on CMD, I see 'hello' being printed...
C:\foo\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -c 'echo hello'
hello

...however when I run the same command on Git Bash, it instead starts an interactive MSYS shell:
/c/foo/msys64/usr/bin/bash -c 'echo hello'

AzureAD+me@DESKTOP-FOO MSYS /c$ 

I've even tried running the command without any environment within Git Bash, but the same thing happens:
env -i /c/foo/msys64/usr/bin/bash -c 'echo hello'

AzureAD+me@DESKTOP-FOO MSYS /c$ 

Also tried with quotes inside the argument to -c, since this is what CMD passes bash.exe:
env -i /c/foo/msys64/usr/bin/bash -c '"echo hello"'

AzureAD+me@DESKTOP-FOO MSYS /c$ 

Any ideas why this happens? The behavior within CMD is obviously the right one, and is what I would have expected to happen on Git Bash as well.
